# How to combine ASCII text files, then encrypt, then decrypt, and put into a 'File' Class? C++

Tags: c++, encryption, file

For example, if I have three ASCII files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

...and I wanted to combine them into one encrypted file:

```
database.txt
```

Then in the application I would decrypt the database.txt and put each of the original files into a 'File' class on the heap:

```
class File{
public:
    string getContents();
    void setContents(string data);
private:
    string m_data;
};
```

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to do in C++.  What is your real question?  What do you want to accomplish with encryption?  If the File class has a setContents function, is that supposed to only change the decrypted version in-memory, or also write the new content back to the encrypted file on disk?

Comment: I just don't want to let the end user to see the files, that's all.  It would decrypt the files in memory.  Thanks

Comment: Users can read memory, too.  If you want to hide data from your typical user, give the file a custom extension (e.g. .dfr for data file for project "r").

Comment: This feels like three issues to me: (1) how to combine 3 files into 1 and then split them again (AKA: archiving, but a specialized case); (2) how to encrypt data for decryption in a program running under the control of the attacker (AKA: DRM, an insoluble problem in general so more information needed); (3) how to copy data into a string contained in a heap-allocated structure. Those are wildly different levels of programming task, do you need help with all three, or is it that you can handle them individually, you're just wondering if there's an especially good way to do all three together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a [zip](http://www.zlib.net/) file?
You can of course roll your own header meta data to store the filenames, but this particular wheel has been re-invented enough times.

If you need better encryption than that provided by zlib, then you can either use the crypt functions in your platform,  or it's very easy to implement something like [blowfish](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish.html)

Comment: Indeed; probably the best solution, unless there are licensing issues or hardware constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pre-existing file format, make your own simple one.

Something like this layout should work:

```
class DatabaseFile {
    private:
        struct FileHeader {
            uint32_t fileId;
            uint32_t fileSize;
            char data[0];
        };

        File readFile(...) {
            read();
            decrypt();
        }

        File writeFile(...) {
            encrypt();
            write();
        }

    public:
        DatabaseFile();
        DatabaseFile(std::vector<File> files);

        static DatabaseFile read(std::istream) {
            while(!eof) {
                readFile();
            }
        }

        void write(std::ostream) {
            foreach(file) {
                writeFile();
            }
        }

        std::vector<File> files;
};

class DatabaseFileEncryption {
    // However you want it ...
};
```